# use of a, the or nothing while describing a routine

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

I have a sentence, describing a general situation, but i am confused about the usage of a, the or nothing in this context.

So in an experiment subjects answer a series of choice questions, in each question they make a choice between two options. If **a** subject chooses option 1, the second option will be changed in the next question.

I am confused because, here the routine or the rule described is valid for all subjects in the experiment, not for a particular subject. But also I state a special case to describe the rule, I mention about a hypothetical subject who chooses option 1. But the rule is valid for all subjects.

Should I use a, the or nothing? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think either "a" or "the" works fine there, with the definite article sounding a bit more natural to me. However, "option 1" doesn't take an article ("the option 1" is ungrammatical), and you can't omit the article before "subject"; it requires one or the other.